# Transaction Control across multiple Containers

Tags: transactions, jms, apache-camel, jta, xa

could you please point me to any sample code for transaction control across multiple containers using XA architecture, JMS and Camel.

Answer (score 2):

here is some general documentation on this to get you started...

http://fusesource.com/docs/esbent/7.0/camel_tx/XaJms-Overview.html